# date field shows calendar far away from the field

Tags: html, css, angularjs

[image: **enter image description here**]

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
  </div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="מתאריך" date-range-picker class="form-control pull-right" ng-model="vm.filter.from.ge" options="{singleDatePicker: true,showDropdowns: true, locale:vm.locale}">
</div>
```

Does anyone know what is causing this problem? The issue is that the calendar is not next to the input field

Comment: Where is your css?

Comment: also post your script for setup date picker